# Апи касперского для браузера

Tags: kaspersky

При установке Касперский ставит плагин для хрома. На сколько я понял, он работает с приложением по некоему протоколу. Где посмотреть доки по этому протоколу?

Comment: С которым из приложений? Учитывая, что это АВ, протокол взаимодействия может быть не опубликован...

Comment: Эм... API Касперского, скорее всего закрыт, можете поискать на их сайте или спросить в поддержке, но он и не нужен для работы плагина. Нужен API хрома для плагинов, через который плагин Касперского управляет поведением хрома.